# format data in views.py for ajax

Tags: django, jquery

I'me trying to use this eventCalendar in django : http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html

I suppose to write ajax codes myself but on the other hand I'me a newbie in jquery ajax,I wanna send event data include startTime,endTime,etc to show them on the calendar:

```
    $('#calendar').weekCalendar({
    data: function(callback){
        $.getJSON("{% url DrHub.views.getEvents %}",
                {
                },
                function(result) {
                        callback(result);
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

this calendar get data in this format:

```
  return {
     events : [
        {
           "id":1,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
           "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
           "title":"Dev Meeting"
        },
        ...
     ]
  };
```

how can I format fetched data from database in `getEvents` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def some_view(request):
    # Build the output -> it's a standard Python dict
    output = {
      "events": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "start": "2009-05-10T13:15:00.000+10:00",
           "end": "2009-05-10T14:15:00.000+10:00",
           "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        },
      ]
    }

    # With db data you would do something like:
    # events = Event.objects.all()
    # for event in events:
    #     event_out = {
    #         "title": event.title,
    #          # other fields here
    #     }
    #     output['events'].append(event_out)

    # Return the output as JSON
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(output), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: thanks so much @Secator ,your answer was great,when I'm going to use database to fill this dict I get this error that "global name 'output' is not defined" and I don't know how to define output out of the loop!I konw my question is rediculous but I didn't know what should I look for to solve this problem!

Comment: when I put this before for loop : output={} ,it cause another error:"Exception Type: KeyError at /doctors/shahsavand/visiting/getEvents/
Exception Value: 'events'" !!

Comment: I solved that problem in another way,tnx buddy,my final problem is that when I save events they are saved in such format:Wed Feb 22 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time), but when I'm going to show theme on calendar they wont be shown because their format doesn't match to calendar date format!I tryed many choices like converting formats when making dict,but no result :( I apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the dictionary as usual, just take into account that strings for dates will not be interpreted in javascript without processing. My advice is to directly send javascript interpretable dates, not strings, as follows:

```
from django.utils import simplejson 
import datetime
import time

occ.start = time.mktime(occ.start.timetuple())*1000
occ.end = time.mktime(occ.end.timetuple())*1000

event = {'id': occ.id,'title':occ.title,'start':occ.start,'end':occ.end,'body':occ.description,'readOnly': '%r' %occ.read_only,'recurring':'%r' % occ.recurring,'persisted': '%r' % occ.persisted,'event_id':occ.event.id}

mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(event),mimetype)
```

take into account that the calendar expects the 'events' key so:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
                res = {events:data};
                //alert(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
                callback(res);
            });
```

If you preffer processing on the javascript side try the library [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) that can convert a date from text.